# Spring Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I start SpringMVC, I get the following exception...

```
    Apr 28, 2012 6:08:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:spring-security-integration' did not find a matching property.
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring3Hibernate' did not find a matching property.
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:assessment' did not find a matching property.
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 601 ms
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Apr 28 18:08:24 BST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c56295f: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 234 ms
Apr 28, 2012 6:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sat Apr 28 18:08:24 BST 2012]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@768404fd: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,homeController,userManagementController,userDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c56295f
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.assessme.com.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/userManagement/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.assessme.com.UserManagementController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/userManagement/getUser],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.assessme.com.entity.User org.assessme.com.UserManagementController.data(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not get database metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The important detail appears to be in ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not get database metadata

My servlet-context.xml is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/assessme" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="toor" />
    </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>org.assessme.com.entity.User</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="data" />
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.assessme.com" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultViews">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <beans:property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

I'm certain the url details and credentials are correct for the database, can anyone think of any other reasons?

It looks like it's trying to access the information_schema db, but in my XML I have set the db it should look at...

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/assessme" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="toor" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Thanks,

David

Comment: I just guess. Do you have any hibernate entity with @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) and mysql supports only generation type AUTO?

Comment: Nah I have @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your error:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not get database metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema
```

You are mapping your MySQL to information_schema which is system database in MySQL and this database does not contain sequances table,

BTW, of the record, you need to take into consideration that MySQL does not have "CREATE Sequance" command.

Comment: yeah I thought this - but in my XML it gets mapped to <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/assessme" />

Comment: (and assessme is the name of the db)

Comment: are you sure that this database exists? as far as I remember Hibernate will not create new database if desired one does not exist, It will use default database, which is "information_schema".

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the db exists, but what's bizarre is if I take the settings from the XML out of spring and use it in hibernate.cfg.xml it works fine with these details.

Comment: is there somewhere else I need to declare the db details or name?

Comment: You are using root account to connect to this DB, I beleive that this might be the problem create new user and grant it appropriate permissions on "assessme" database.

Comment: I just created a user and got the same error :< what's interesting is say I put the invalid dburl in (append an x to the url) it does give me a different error so it must be getting to at least the server...

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but of the record, you should not  use <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop> with any transaction Manager except JTA.

Comment: Second what is <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</beans:prop> you should use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead.

Comment: Thanks, it was the dialect that was wrong and causing the issue :)

Answer (score 23):

*I'm extracting the correct answer to this question from the comments of a different answer.*

This Exception gets thrown because your used dialect doesn't match the database.

In your configuration you use

```
<beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</beans:prop>
```

although you're accessing a `MySQL` database. You should use a `MySQL` dialect instead. E.g.

```
<beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</beans:prop>
```

Answer (score 2):

let you add this in the application.properties file

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

the the error will be disappeared.