# SpringBoot/Hibernate deploy w/MySQL on Windows not working, originally developed on Linux - SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, linux, windows, hibernate

Trying to deploy an app (SpringBoot) to a Windows instance ... app was developed and runs fine on Linux. Even ran fine on Windows when using the H2 file-based profile/mode. Get the following stack trace. Thought it might be a sql dialect issue. Ensured that the dialect is specific. Server is MySQL 5.7. Confirmed on two diff. Win. instances ... same error.

Any thoughts/tips?

**Hibernate/JPA Settings:**

```
spring:
  profiles: WinProfile
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbNameHere
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: **************
    password: **************
    initialize: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

**Output**

```
     .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)

2018-02-15 16:52:15.766  WARN 1872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator        : HHH000409: Using org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator which does not generate IETF RFC 4122 compliant UUID values; consider using org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator instead
2018-02-15 16:52:17.391  WARN 1872 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1109, SQLState: 42S02
2018-02-15 16:52:17.391 ERROR 1872 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema
2018-02-15 16:52:17.391  WARN 1872 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-02-15 16:52:17.437  WARN 1872 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2018-02-15 16:52:17.453 ERROR 1872 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.astechconsulting.docgen.DocgenApplication.main(DocgenApplication.java:31) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [docgen-0.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [docgen-0.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [docgen-0.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [docgen-0.0.1.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error creating DatabaseInformation for schema migration
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2448) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1381) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why did you think it was a SQL dialect issue?

Comment: Are you using sequences for IDs somewhere? Because MySQL doesn't support Sequences, only auto increment

Comment: Using uuid's (generated in java, varchar in DB) as primary keys. No specific sequencing set up.

Comment: @RomanC - as to why maybe dialect. First deploy, I hadn't explicitly put it in  the settings

Comment: Why didn't you put it in the settings?

Comment: @RomanC - initial omission ... I thought it might be an issue. Turned out it's not. Trying to sort what it might be that's not that.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what part of the update did it ... but I believe it was the *dialect:* && the *database:* properties ... I also added the *globally_quoted_identifiers* used in another profile that was working ... not sure how I missed that before, but it's working now:

```
---
spring:
  profiles: WinProfile
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbNameHere
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: #################
    password: ####################
    initialize: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    database: MYSQL
    properties:
          hibernate:
            globally_quoted_identifiers: true
```

Comment: For me it was the missing dialect

Answer (score 0):

Check your console:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema
```

You are mapping your MySQL to information_schema which is system database in MySQL and this database does not contain sequances table,

BTW, of the record, you need to take into consideration that MySQL does not have "CREATE Sequance" command.

References: [Spring Hibernate Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365753/spring-hibernate-exception)

Comment: Thanks ... This is inherited code that I'm trying to get working in a new env. I have not added any 'sequences'. My Hibernate-fu is rather rusty ... what would be indicative of instructions for hibernate to "Create Sequence"?